# Error: ORA-00917: missing comma 00917. 00000 - "missing comma"

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am getting missing comma error but where am i missing that comma?

```
DELETE FROM user_sdo_geom_metadata WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VIEW_POINT';
INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata
(TABLE_NAME,
 COLUMN_NAME,
 DIMINFO,
 SRID)
 VALUES (
'VIEW_POINT',
'GEOMETRY',
 MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY( -- upper and lower bounds for the view, tolerance
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -180, 180, 0.5),
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', -90, 90, 0.5)),
  SRID FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME ='AG_POINTS'
)
;
 commit;
```

Comment: `SRID FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME ='AG_POINTS'` - if it is a subquery, it should contains SELECT and be enclosed in brackets - `(SELECT SRID FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME ='AG_POINTS')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the source of the insert data is a `SELECT` statement you can't use the `values` clause:

```
INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata
  (table_name, column_name,diminfo, srid)
SELECT 'VIEW_POINT',
       'GEOMETRY',
       mdsys.sdo_dim_array( -- upper and lower bounds for the view, tolerance
         mdsys.sdo_dim_element('X', -180, 180, 0.5),
         mdsys.sdo_dim_element('Y', -90, 90, 0.5)),
       srid 
FROM user_sdo_geom_metadata 
WHERE table_name = 'AG_POINTS'
```

;

Answer (score 1):

Use INSERT INTO..SELECT syntax

```
INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
(TABLE_NAME,
 COLUMN_NAME,
 DIMINFO,
 SRID)
 SELECT  
'VIEW_POINT',
'GEOMETRY',
 MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY( -- upper and lower bounds for the view, tolerance
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -180, 180, 0.5),
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', -90, 90, 0.5),
  SRID FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME ='AG_POINTS'
)
;
```